# breezejs: trying to configure breeze with standard ODATA service

Tags: javascript, breeze

After working for months with a breeze WebAPI controller, I'm now about to start a new project with a standard WebAPI controller (I'm not that excited about it and I've got a bad feeling not being able to fully rely on breeze...)

Anyway, I'm trying to configure breeze on the client side and I'm running into an exception:

´Cannot get property « jsonResultsAdapter »  of an undefined or null reference´

Here's how I've configured breezejs.

- I've added datajs.js to my project (and to the html page of course)
- breeze service configuration

  ```
  var service = new breeze.DataService({
     serviceName: ('http://localhost:52446/api'),        
     adapterName: 'OData'
   });

  var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: service });


  //skip irrelevant code



  function search() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Mandate");

    return manager.executeQuery(query.using(service)).then(function (result) {
    }).fail(function (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    });
  }
  ```

When I debug breezejs:

```
  proto.using = function (obj) {
    if (!obj) return this;
    var eq = this._clone();
    processUsing(eq, {
        entityManager: null,
        dataService: null,
        queryOptions: null,
        fetchStrategy: function (eq, val) { eq.queryOptions = (eq.queryOptions || new QueryOptions()).using(val) },
        mergeStrategy: function (eq, val) { eq.queryOptions = (eq.queryOptions || new QueryOptions()).using(val) },
        jsonResultsAdapter: function (eq, val) { eq.dataService = (eq.dataService || new DataService()).using({ jsonResultsAdapter: val }) }
    }, obj);
    return eq;
};
```

jsonResultAdapter is null and not set.

Why is that ?

Comment: can I see a fiddle or plnkr of this? I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it to work by adding the following line before the creation of the EntityManager:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
```

Breeze Team, can you just explain why I need to do that, since I've already set adpaterName: "OData" in the DataService.....  ?